# Curl download to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, curl, hdfs

I had this code:

```
curl -o fileName.csv url | xargs hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal $1 /somePath/
```

When i execute this code, curl put the values from request inside fileName.csv, the file are moved to HDFS. I wanna know if i can, mantain the curl output in memory, send to pipe and just write the values inside HDFS?

Something like this(that works):

```
curl url | xargs hdfs dfs -put $1 /somePath
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hdfs dfs -put` command can accept file input from stdin, using the familiar idiom of specifying `-` to mean stdin:

```
> curl -sS https://www.google.com/robots.txt | hdfs dfs -put - /robots.txt
> hdfs dfs -ls /robots.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 cnauroth supergroup       6880 2017-07-06 09:07 /robots.txt
```

Another option is to use shell [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to allow treating the stdout of `curl` (or really any command you choose) as if it were a file input to another command:

```
> hdfs dfs -put <(curl -sS https://www.google.com/robots.txt) /robots.txt
> hdfs dfs -ls /robots.txt
-rw-r--r--   3 cnauroth supergroup       6880 2017-07-05 15:07 /robots.txt
```

Comment: @philantrovert , yes, thank you!  Great catch.  I forgot about this.  We just don't have it documented as clearly for `-put` as we do for `-appendToFile`.  I corrected the answer.