# Download data directly into HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Similar questions have been asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454244/stream-data-into-hdfs-directly-without-copying) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936241/curl-download-to-hdfs)) but my question is different in that I'm wondering if there's a way to directly download data (either from a REST API or cURL) into an HDFS cluster.

I'm trying to avoid saving the file locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webHDFS REST API, but this is a two-steps operation. To specifically upload a file:

Step 1:

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE
                    [&overwrite=<true|false>][&blocksize=<LONG>][&replication=<SHORT>]
                    [&permission=<OCTAL>][&buffersize=<INT>]"
```

Step 2:

```
curl -i -X PUT -T <LOCAL_FILE> "http://<DATANODE>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE..."
```

In step 2:
You decide how to pass `<LOCAL_FILE>` and the URL `http://<DATANODE>:<PORT>` is the one returned by step 2.

More information of this operation in [Create and Write to a File](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE)